# setInterval не выключается

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

Всем привет, ребят помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с функцией. Много времени убил, не знаю в чем проблема. Функция должна работать так, когда зажимаю кнопку мыши, функция должна работать непрерывно, а когда отпускаю кнопку, то прекращать выполнение. Но очень часто функция зависает и clearInterval продолжает бесконечно добавлять блоки на страницу. В чем может быть проблема?

```
function showGifts() {
  let intervalMousedown;
  let intervalMouseup;
  let offsetX;
  let offsetY;

  function renderItems() {
    let gift = document.createElement('div');
    

    $('body').append(
      $(gift)
        .clone()
        .offset({
          left: offsetX - 10,
          top: offsetY - 30,
        }),
    );
  }

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    clearTimeout(intervalMouseup);

    intervalMousedown = setInterval(() => {
      renderItems();
    }, 60);
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    let arr = document.querySelectorAll('.gift');
    clearInterval(intervalMousedown);

    intervalMouseup = setTimeout(() => {
      arr.forEach((gift) => {
        gift.remove();
      });
    }, 4100);
  });

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    offsetX = e.pageX;
    offsetY = e.pageY;
  });
}

showGifts();
```

Comment: Создали [timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3YEG.png), удаляйте [interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzIXK.png).

Comment: Спасибо, этот баг не заметил, но к удивлению это все равно не помогает =((

Comment: А что на что вы заменили?

Comment: Как вы сказали, сделал clearTimeout(intervalMouseup); вместо clearInterval(intervalMouseup);

Answer (score 1):

Проблема с зависанием функции может быть связана с тем, что внутри функции `renderItems()` создается новый элемент `div` с классом `gift` и добавляется в тело документа `($('body'))`. Если пользователь многократно нажимает на кнопку мыши, то может создаться большое количество элементов, что может привести к значительному замедлению работы браузера.
Для решения этой проблемы можно использовать механизм, который будет проверять количество созданных элементов div и удалять их при превышении определенного значения. Например, можно добавить следующий код внутри функции `renderItems()`

```
const maxGifts = 50;
const gifts = document.querySelectorAll('.gift');
if (gifts.length >= maxGifts) {
  gifts[0].remove();
}

let gift = document.createElement('div');
gift.classList.add('gift');
$('body').append(
  $(gift).clone().offset({
    left: offsetX - 10,
    top: offsetY - 30,
  })
);
```

Также может быть полезным добавить проверку на наличие активных интервалов перед их очисткой, чтобы избежать ошибок. Например, можно использовать следующий код для очистки интервалов:

```
if (intervalMousedown) {
  clearInterval(intervalMousedown);
}
if (intervalMouseup) {
  clearTimeout(intervalMouseup);
}
```

Если проблема сохраняется даже после добавления кода, который я предложил ранее, то может быть полезно проверить другие причины зависания функции.

Одна из возможных причин - это то, что не все созданные элементы div удаляются после отпускания кнопки мыши. Это может приводить к тому, что многие элементы остаются на странице, что замедляет ее работу и вызывает зависание.

Чтобы убедиться, что все элементы удаляются корректно, вы можете добавить вывод в консоль количества элементов div перед и после их удаления:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  let arr = document.querySelectorAll('.gift');
  console.log(`before remove: ${arr.length}`);
  clearInterval(intervalMousedown);

  intervalMouseup = setTimeout(() => {
    arr.forEach((gift) => {
      gift.remove();
    });
    console.log(`after remove: ${document.querySelectorAll('.gift').length}`);
  }, 4100);
});
```

Если проблема сохраняется, можно попробовать изменить частоту создания элементов div в функции renderItems(), чтобы уменьшить количество элементов, создаваемых за короткий промежуток времени. Например, можно увеличить интервал до 100 миллисекунд

```
intervalMousedown = setInterval(() => {
  renderItems();
}, 100);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет) попробовал, все равно функция зависает и не отключается

Comment: @Роман Обновил ответ.